# Connect pgadmin to RDS AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: windows, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect my RDS postgres SQL databade to my pgAdmin III to see the BBDD and add data but the connection launches the following one error:
[pgAdmin message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wk8n.png)

My pg_hba.config have the following one configuration:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections: host    all             all           127.0.0.1/32            md5    
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5    
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32           md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                md5
```

and my postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      
port = 5432             
max_connections = 100
```

I have configured the firewall rules in my windows desktop, for the pgadmin be able to communicate through TCP for the 5432 port.

I also Attach the variables of the connection:[pgadmin connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew3FG.png)

Thanks, If you can help me, I'll it grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your security group has an entry for port 5432 on TCP.

Comment: I leave my configuration of security group in other comment.

Answer (score 0):

I leave my configuration of security group:
Group name:
awseb-e-ds3pmf8tx8-stack-AWSEBRDSDBSecurityGroup-G0BCKWC2QTGH

Group description:
Enable database access to Beanstalk application

Group ID:
sg-39ce5252

VPC ID:
vpc-ead84082

INBOUND:

Type:
All TCP
Protocol:
TCP
Port range:
0 - 65535
Source:
sg-d2fa6ab9 (awseb-e-ds3pmf8tx8-stack

OUTBOUND

Type:
All trafic
Protocol:
All
Port Range:
All
Destination:
0.0.0.0/0